# Working with Instance count in worker role

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

While using multiple instances in worker role will there not be thread synchronization issues. My doubt is whether two instances might try to pick the same record and process the same.  How to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not *threading* issues, but *concurrency* issues. Yes, there will be issues.

However, these issues are **not different from normal concurrency issues** that you might have with even a single web server receiving simultaneous requests.

The most common way to deal with concurrency issues is through the use of [Optimistic Concurrency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

a common solution within the Windows Azure Platform for allocating work out to multiple worker processes is the use of Azure Storage Queues. This helps minimize the risk of two threads or even two roles working on a single item concurrently. However, there is a wee bit of additional work that is required to make this fully functional and ensure that the queue behavior is properly accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recomend use multiple single-thread roles in order to avoid threading. It would be more expensive,  and as @Mark has pointed out, you will end facing almost the same problems.